# A way to pull code from a nvarchar column in a SQL Server database and execute it as code in my application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Is there a framework out there that can read a string of C# that is pulled from a database and run it as code?

Kind of like a calculator works...

I just want an idea of how hard it is to do something like this. Or to develop something that can make it happen.

Let's say there is a `nvarchar` column that I return from a database that has something like this in it:

```
(a + b - c)
```

In my code I know what a, b, and c are equivalent to, but how do I replace the values and get it to run as code? Essentially it is what a compiler does.

If you want to disregard the SQL part, how would I execute a string with a formula in it as code in my application:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 1;
string formula = "(a + b - c)"
```

Comment: Example dataset/outcome? What have you already done?

Comment: Read the code.  Put it into a file.  Compile the file appropriately.  Run the executable.

Comment: I updated my post with a little more information, but the formulas could be a lot more complex.

Comment: @ZoffDino not sure if that is what I need. The goal is to be able to take a string of code and execute it as code. We can disregard the sql part.

Comment: Do you want to execute it locally (in your C# client), or on the server (as stored procedure)?

Comment: In my C# client as C# code. Why is this post getting downvoted? I feel like it is pretty straightforward and is a good question for a programmer just starting out to ask. Please see my updated post.

Comment: @MatthewPeterson Downvotes are a plague here. Upvote from my side.

Comment: I think the existing post marked as duplicate answers my question. Too bad I didn't find it before posting this one. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use SQL server for "calculating", then it would be totally simple. You could put some T-SQL code in your `nvarchar` database field, and then let it execute it at runtime on the server. (Basically this is then Dynamic SQL)

Comment: So you saying if all of the calculations / formulas could be written as sql then i could store them as strings and run them using sp_executesql? How would I handle plugging in the variables of the formulas?

Comment: @matthewpeterson yes exactly, with sp_execute! and even parameters can be passed from outside, thats pretty cool.  i'll show you later, i'm out at nightlife currently! ;)